# Sleuth support for Jersey

Tags: java, spring, spring-cloud-sleuth, opentracing

We are using Spring with Jersey on both client and server sides. How to use sleuth in such a configuration?

`org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-starter-sleuth` does not support jersey by default. I guess custom implementation must be provided, does any one have some reference implementation?

On client side I created filter that adds tracing info to the headers:

```
@Component
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class TracingClientRequestFilter implements ClientRequestFilter {

    public static final String TRACE_ID_HEADER = "X-B3-TraceId";
    public static final String SPAN_ID_HEADER = "X-B3-SpanId";

    private final Tracer tracer;

    @Override
    public void filter(ClientRequestContext requestContext) throws IOException {
        Optional.ofNullable(tracer.currentSpan())
                .map(Span::context)
                .ifPresent(traceContext ->  {
                    requestContext.getHeaders().add(TRACE_ID_HEADER, traceContext.traceId());
                    requestContext.getHeaders().add(SPAN_ID_HEADER, traceContext.spanId());
                });
    }
}
```

On server side I created filter that extracts tracing info:

```
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class TracingFilter2 extends OncePerRequestFilter {

    public static final String TRACE_ID_HEADER = "X-B3-TraceId";
    public static final String SPAN_ID_HEADER = "X-B3-SpanId";

    private final Tracer tracer;

    @Override
    protected void doFilterInternal(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse res, FilterChain chain) throws ServletException, IOException {
        CurrentTraceContext currentTraceContext = tracer.currentTraceContext();
        String traceId = req.getHeader(TRACE_ID_HEADER);
        String spanId = req.getHeader(SPAN_ID_HEADER);
        if (currentTraceContext == null || StringUtils.isBlank(traceId) || StringUtils.isBlank(spanId)) {
            chain.doFilter(req, res);
        } else {
            TraceContext traceContext = tracer.traceContextBuilder().traceId(traceId).spanId(spanId).build();
            CurrentTraceContext.Scope span = currentTraceContext.newScope(traceContext);
            try (span) {
                chain.doFilter(req, res);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Is this correct approach? Should I reuse both spanId and traceId or should spanId be generated? What about parentId?